# Convert Jquery calendar button click in to angular directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I want to convert my jquery button click code in to angular directive.
my code is:

```
$('.fc-month-button').click();
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason for that ?

Comment: yes. in full year calendar, i hide default month and year view button. and i set dropdown for change calendar view.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJs controller code

```
   var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.yourFunction = function(){
        //TODO
      };
    });
```

This is code sample for ng directive

```
app.directive('ngClick', [
      function () {
          return {
              link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                  var msg = attr.ngClick || "Are you sure?";
                  var clickAction = attr.confirmedClick;
                  element.bind('click', function (event) {
                      if (window.confirm(msg)) {
                          scope.$eval(clickAction)
                      }
                  });
              }
          };
```